# Webmin MySQL client - not server

Tags: mysql, webmin

I have a class with 30 students. They use Webmin to access their public_html directory, edit files, and such. They will be starting on their database soon. Each student has his/her own database in MySQL. Webmin has a MySQL module that I thought I could use. I cannot. If one person logs into the MySQL module in webmin, everyone is logged into MySQL as that user. I can't have 30 students logged in as 30 different users. The reason is obvious. The MySQL module is for server administration. It is not a MySQL client.

Is there a MySQL client module for Webmin that will allow me to have 30 students logged in as 30 different users using 30 different databases at the same time? I know that I will likely have to install phpmyadmin, but I'd prefer to keep it one interface to simplify things for the students.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just install mysql workbench on each client machine and ask your students to connect individually to the database server with their own credentials?

Comment: @PaulCampbell The workstations are imaged by IT services. Getting them to add a program requires an act of God - and even that rarely works.

Comment: I thought those days were long gone. Next option (and you can see I'm trying to steer you away from phpmyadmin), how about giving them login accounts on the server and letting them use the command-line tool? That's still my primary means of interacting with mysql, plus your students would learn some command-line editing skills at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [Virtualmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/) module for Webmin that would help you to manage users with ease.

You just need to run `install.sh` script to have GPL version installed.

```
wget http://software.virtualmin.com/gpl/scripts/install.sh
```